# Angular2: Having a fixed element positioned by relation to its parent

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular

I want to have a fixed element by posisioned according to its parent and not the browser. I have thus design a (quick and dirty) angular2 directive :

My template

```
<div class="main" style="position: relative">
        <div style="position: absolute" positioningFromParent="left" [additionalPixels]=20>
           ...
        </div>
</div>
```

My Angular2 Directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from "angular2/core"

@Directive({
    selector: "[positioningFromParent]"
})
export class PositioningFromParent implements OnInit {
    private el:HTMLElement
    @Input() positioningFromParent: string = ""
    @Input() additionalPixels: number = 0

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement
    }
   ngOnInit() {
     let v = this.el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()[this.positioningFromParent]
     this.el.style[this.positioningFromParent] = (v + this.additionalPixels).toString() + "px"
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't work as the width of my main element is set dynamically (I can't specify it). When the `ngOnInit` runs, it gives me a width of 0 as its width only comes later. How could I "watch" the parent's width in angular2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is not ready in `ngOnInit()` use [`ngAfterViewInit()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html) instead.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit } from "angular2/core"

@Directive({
    selector: "[positioningFromParent]"
})
export class PositioningFromParent implements AfterViewInit {
    private el:HTMLElement
    @Input() positioningFromParent: string = ""
    @Input() additionalPixels: number = 0

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement
    }
   ngAfterViewInit() {
     let v = this.el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()[this.positioningFromParent]
     this.el.style[this.positioningFromParent] = (v + this.additionalPixels).toString() + "px"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook instead of `ngOnInit`, because this will be called after the actual DOM elements have been created (`ngOnInit` is only called once the component's inputs have been resolved). Using `ngAfterViewInit` should mean the parent's width is non-zero by the time the code inside that function runs.